# Jackson xml empty element serialization

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I'm having a hard time with this one. Jackson 2.2 XML serializer seems to serialize empty object fields this way:

```
<field/>
```

How can I force it to serialize such empty field like this:

```
<field></field>
```

Thank you very much for your time and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, see this question: [How do you override the null serializer in Jackson 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101506/how-do-you-override-the-null-serializer-in-jackson-2-0). For `XmlMapper` it could look like below. Create `NullSerializer`:

```
class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

and simple usage:

```
XmlSerializerProvider provider = new XmlSerializerProvider(new XmlRootNameLookup());
provider.setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setSerializerProvider(provider);

System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new Entity()));
```

Above program prints:

```
<Entity xmlns=""><field></field></Entity>
```