# Handling empty XML nodes when converting to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, deserialization

I read in an XML file (provided by another system, so I cannot control it) in order to convert it to JSON. Using Jackson. I am seeing some undesirable behavior where any "empty" nodes in the source XML file are being converted to JSON with "\n <many spaces if source is indented>" as the content. For example:

Generated output:

```
{"a":"Dummy Content","b":"\n "}
```

Desired output:

```
{"a":"Dummy Content","b":""}
```

What is the most acceptable way to correct this in a generic enough way that it will work on any XML file with any empty XML nodes?

When loading the file, I tried iterating each line to clear it up like this:

```
String content = "";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyFile.xml"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        content += line.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "").trim();
    }
}
```

It appears to work however I was wondering if there is a better solution? The source XML files could be quite large (hundreds of thousands of lines).

Sample code that illustrates the issue

```
private static String testXML
    = "<Root>\n"
    + " <a>Dummy Content</a>\n"
    + " <b>\n"
    + " </b>\n"
    + "</Root>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = null;
    try {
        jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(testXML);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    System.out.println(jsonNode);
}
```

Generated Output:

```
{"a":"Dummy Content","b":"\n "}
```

Desired output:

```
{"a":"Dummy Content","b":""}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson xml empty element serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125995/jackson-xml-empty-element-serialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deserialise `XML` to `JsonNode` you can override `JsonNodeFactory` which creates nodes with data. For `String` we need to override `textNode` method and in case value [is blank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-), just [trim it to empty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#trimToEmpty-java.lang.String-) `String`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class XmlApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String testXML = "<Root>\n <a>Dummy Content</a>\n <b>\n </b>\n</Root>";

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.setNodeFactory(new TrimStringTextJsonNodeFactory());

    JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(testXML);

    System.out.println(jsonNode);
  }
}

class TrimStringTextJsonNodeFactory extends JsonNodeFactory {

  @Override
  public TextNode textNode(String text) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(text)) {
      text = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(text);
    }
    return super.textNode(text);
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"a":"Dummy Content","b":""}
```

Comment: This appears to work beautifully! I knew there had to be a solution within Jackson but this is the first time i have played with it, so appreciate the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace all special characters to empty one first:

```
testXml = testXml.replaceAll('\n', '');
```

Comment: Correct, that will remove the newline characters but leaves the whitespace from any indentation. ie: {"a":"Dummy Content","b":"                     "}. I need something that leaves the attribute truly empty.

Answer (score 1):

Apply an XSLT transformation to the XML before converting it to JSON. You can't expect a general purpose library to do semantic conversions (like treating "\n" and "" as equivalent). You need to do this as a separate step either before or after the XML-to-JSON conversion, and doing it before is easier because there is more tooling available.

Don't try and do the transformation on the lexical XML before parsing: you're likely to break the XML. For example, removing a newline that separates two attributes within a start tag would produce ill-formed XML.

Comment: My experience with XSLT is very limited, any chance of an example please?