# Deserialise JSON payload to JsonNode with custom logic

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I want to deserialise a `String` to `JsonNode` while converting all doubles to ints where possible. For example, with the following code

```
// str is = { "a": 1.0, "b": 0.5 }
var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode n = objectMapper.readTree(str);
```

**Current behavior:** Both children of `n` are type `DoubleNode`.

**Goal**: For the children of `n`, `a` is type `IntNode` and `b` is type `DoubleNode`.

I've seen a lot of custom deserializers on here but they only apply to defined POJOs and not arbitrary `JsonNode` deserialization. Would appreciate any help on how to customize the string to `JsonNode` deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to preprocess the input JSON string and remove the fractional part containing only `0`s along with the fractional dot `.`:

```java
String str = "{ \"a\": \"1.0\", \"b\": 0.5, \"c\":\"0.01\", \"d\": 0.00}"
  .replaceAll("(\\d+)\\.0+(\\D)", "$1$2")); // check if fractional part contains only 0's

System.out.println(str);
```

Here `"$1$2"` refer to the first `(\\d+)` (non-empty sequence of digits) and the second `(\\D)` (any non-digit character) matching groups which should be kept after the replacement.

Output:

```
{ "a": "1", "b": 0.5, "c":"0.01", "d": 0}
```

Then `a` and `d` can be parsed as integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you deserialise `JSON` to `JsonNode` you can override `JsonNodeFactory` which creates nodes with data. Example:

```
JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .nodeFactory(new JsonNodeFactory(true) {
            @Override
            public NumericNode numberNode(double v) {
                if (v == (int) v) {
                    return super.numberNode((int) v);
                }
                if (v == (long) v) {
                    return super.numberNode((long) v);
                }
                return super.numberNode(v);
            }
        })
        .build();
```

As you can see, you can define which type of node will be created for a given value.

Similar question:

- [Handling empty XML nodes when converting to JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566113/handling-empty-xml-nodes-when-converting-to-json-using-jackson)