# How to force closing tag on empty or null value in jackson's XmlMapper?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Currently doing some transformations for object to xml string using jackson's XmlMapper. Using the default configuration i get:

```
<root>
   <field1 />
   <field2 />
</root>
```

but client wants to receive:

```
<root>
   <field1></field1>
   <field2></field2>
</root>
```

where my source object's field1 is an empty string ("") and field 2 is a null object. Is this something that can be configured in one of Jackson's features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a `NullSerializer` class extends `JsonSerializer`. Then rewrite the method inside.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125995/jackson-xml-empty-element-serialization) is a similar question.