# Convert "--" to NULL when serializing/deserializing with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I use Jackon to convert simple data classes to Map with

```
new ObjectMapper().convert(map, MyData.class); 
// or vice versa
new ObjectMapper().convert(myData, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
```

Now I have the requirement that the Map should contain the String "--" as value whenever the data object has a NULL value and I already have two methods that iterate over the Map entries and swap the values.

Is there a Jackson annotation that would call those convertes automatically?

I already tried `@JsonSerialize(converter=…)` and `@JsonDeserialize(converter=…)` but it did not seem to work. Would that have been the right approach or is there a better one?

Comment: you mean `--` as value?

Comment: See [How do you override the null serializer in Jackson 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101506/how-do-you-override-the-null-serializer-in-jackson-2-0) and [JSON Jackson custom deserializer to return empty String instead of null](http://apieceofmycode.blogspot.com/2015/05/json-jackson-custom-deserializer-to.html). Do you want to handle any type or only `String` properties?

Comment: @Deadpool: sorry my above sentence was broken: all NULL  values from the Object have to be converted into "--" Map values.

Comment: @MichałZiober : I also have to convert the other way around, from "--" in the Map to NULL in the Object.

Comment: You try to convert `MyData` to `Map<String, String>`. Does it mean that all properties in `MyData` class are `String`?

Comment: MyObject has String, Integer, Double properties. But no nested structures.